# WebClient maximum file download size

Tags: vb.net, file, download, size, webclient

I'm stuck with a little problem in a download manager I'm working on.
At the moment it kinda works as it should but whenever I request it to download some larger files (2gb) it just crashes.
It says the problem is in the `TotalBytesToReceive` code but I really don't know what to do at this point.

```
Public Class
Private WithEvents httpclient As WebClient

Private Sub Button12_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    TextBox19.Text = "11"
    httpclient = New WebClient
    Dim download As String = TextBox25.Text
    Dim save As String = TextBox2.Text
    httpclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(download), save)
```

Error code:

> An exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in Quantum Settings.exe but was not handled in user code

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You must show a bit of code for understand. Now i can just say that maybe you use a INTEGER as size of your file, try with a LONG.. or maybe you use a stream that cannot contain file more large als 2GB.. or maybe...
As i said, without a code, we cannot help you :D

Comment: Just updated it a bit

Comment: Well.. im pretty sure that `Webclient` will read the file into memory. So use `WebClient.DownloadFile` instead of `DownloadFileAsync`. Give a try.

Comment: Having some problems with atm but gonna test it out for sure! Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Tyler : `DownloadFileAsync` is just an asynchronous version of  `DownloadFile`. None of them download the file into memory. The [**`DownloadData` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f(v=vs.110).aspx) does, however.

Comment: @Tyler : Also, the problem was an `OverflowException`, not `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @Haxcha : You must show the code where the error occurs, not only when you start downloading the file. Keep in mind that we know nothing about your code, and we must be able to reproduce this or at least be able to see what the cause could be.

Comment: @Haxcha : Also, for future reference when asking questions: Write the name of the actual class you are using, _**not only**_ the name of your variable -- I am saying this because your title was very misleading since you were talking about a `WebClient`, but there are other classes called `Http***`.